# Why does user abort stop server script execution in firefox?

Tags: javascript, php

Following (php) script does not write data to file when triggered by XmlHttpRequest from FIREFOX, but it works from CHROME and EDGE - any idea why?

```
<script>

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "?data=test", true);
  xhttp.send();
  location.href = "https://www.google.com";

</script>

<?php

  if(isset($_GET["data"]) === true)
  {
    ignore_user_abort(true);

    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "file.txt", $_GET["data"]);
  }

?>
```

Comment: Because a race condition of the http call and the browser reloading. You should redirect when the Ajax cal is done.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that xhttp.send() is sync and everything else waits for the request (not response) to be sent. ps.: readyState === 1 solved it.